# What is the difference between the Honor Roll and the Dean's List?

Tags: differences, synonyms, lists

I can't really find a clear answer for this question. I would appreciate if someone does know how to differentiate between the two. Thanks!

Comment: The "Dean's List" is the Honror Roll at an institution that has a dean.  Perhaps a secondary school has an Honor Roll, while a university has a Dean's List.

Comment: Depends entirely on the regulations of the institution granting the rewards.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about American culture, not the English language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some schools have either an Honor Roll or a Dean's List. Other schools have both, and might even have a President's List, too.

It is ultimately up to an academic institution to define what these designations mean. However, for schools that have both designations, **the criteria for making the Dean's List is usually more difficult than the criteria for making the Honor Roll**. For example, the GPA requirement for Honor Roll might be 3.5 or higher, and the GPA requirement for Dean's List might be 3.75 to 3.99. There could be other criteria such as no grade below a C-.

I suppose you could be awarded both designations, but it's more common for a student to be awarded the one designation with the more stringent criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out in the comments, these phrases have **no** established meanings as parts of the English language. They exist **only** as institution-specific technical terms. The meanings that they have within the setting of a particular institution should be sought in the regulations of that institution, not in a dictionary.